# SQL Rights Creator/Owner

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, privileges, rights

Our software has data to store, so it also install MYSQL, a root user and a user with read only access if a third party compagny wants to install a backup solution for our data. But the third party wants to write data (a timestamp for backup purpose or something like that...) to another database. How can I change the user so it has read only acces to our database and creator/owner rights to other databases.

Second part of my question : we **migth** switch to POSTGRES later. Does the creator/owner right (or the equivalent solution) exists in POSTGRES as well ?

Am I clear enough ?

Comment: I have not found anything that indicates that such a thing exists. I would to close / delete or some other form of withdrawing my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few searches I've found nothing that indicates that such a thing exists.

Comment: longneck's answer should've put you in the right direction, as it *does* exist.  Specifically, see the syntax for REVOKE and then use GRANT to give them back the minimal access you want them to have.

Comment: And it can give them access to specifically databases and tables they create and no write access to already existing tables ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to read this page from the mysql manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html

this page describes how to grant permissions to existing and new users with the restrictions you have requested.